# Correct programming with namespaces

Tags: c++

I wonder what is the right way to use namespace while calling functions or using classes from libraries. Should I always call a function in the format `namespace::func()`?

I'm a little bit confused because when I'm trying to use the function `cout` from `<iostream>` I always need to add the library namespace - `std::cout`.

But when I'm trying to call a function from `<ctime>` library which belongs to `std` namespace, I don't need to add the namespace before the function name.

Why is that?

Comment: Some functions are adopted from the global namespace regarding their plain c implementations are available.

Comment: mostly, in a module file, i would declare `using namespace XXX;` and use without `XXX::`, but in headers, i would not declare `using namespace XXX;` so it wont affect includers without their will.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [`<ctime>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/ctime) header is a [backward-compatibility header file](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header#C_compatibility_headers) against the old C roots of C++. Such compatibility headers can (and usually do) put their function *both* in the `std` namespace *and* in the global namespace.

Thus a function like [`std::time`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/time) can be reached both as `std::time` and `time`.